# How to remove one specific category (uncategorized) from post permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have several posts on my wordpress site. 
Most of them belong to a specific category, but some don't.

For all the posts that belong to a category I want to have the following permalink structure:
/%category%/%postname%/

All the other default posts belong "automatically" to the uncategorized category.
Their URL structure will look like this /uncategorized/%postname%/

I want to change permalinks to the following: /%postname%/

Is there a way to make an exception for the permalinks that belong to the uncategorized category?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked the permalink option from admin side.

Comment: I have. But it's only possible to define one permalink structure for all posts. I defined /%category%/%postname%/ there. But I want to have a different permalink structure for all posts that belong to the uncategorized category.. Do you have any idea to implement this?

Comment: there is a plugin for permalinks you can try that
link: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-permalinks
but it is not updated since a long time. you can try if it would work for you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that plugin is buggy according to the developer reviews. I hope another solution is available

Answer (score 1):

[The solution bellow](http://wordpress.webmasters.answers.ninja/post/133575) worked for me.

In function.php, just add :

```
if the post is category "uncategorized" or child of "uncategorized" as the main category, change the permalink rule of "/%category%/%postname%" to "/%postname%"

function my_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  if( $post->post_type != 'post' ) return $permalink;
  $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
  if( ! count($cats) ) return $permalink;

  usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID');
  $category_object = apply_filters( 'post_link_category', $cats[0], $cats, $post );

  $category_object = get_term( $category_object, 'category' );

  return _clear_uncategorized($category_object, $permalink);
}

function _clear_uncategorized($cat, $permalink) {
  if( $cat->slug == 'uncategorized' ) {
    return str_replace('%category%/', '', $permalink);
  }
  $parent = $cat->parent;
  if ( !$parent )
    return $permalink;
  return _clear_uncategorized($parent, $permalink);
}

add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'my_pre_post_link', 9, 3 );
```

Comment: This is not working for me, when I tried to access to the link the site shows always the 404 page. I think the problem is on htaccess but I can´t solve this issue.